# AVOptions for video size components

Tags: c, ffmpeg

There is an option for declaring video size:

```
av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0);
```

Are there any equivalent options for the size components? Like:

```
av_dict_set_int(&options, VIDEO_WIDTH_OPT_STR , 1920, 0);
av_dict_set_int(&options, VIDEO_HEIGHT_OPT_STR, 1080, 0);
```

What would be the values for those macros (if any)?

```
#define VIDEO_WIDTH_OPT_STR  "?"
#define VIDEO_HEIGHT_OPT_STR "?"
```

*Please note I'm aware of `man snprintf`, that's not my concern, thank you.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add whatever you want in the dictionary, it's just a container. `video_size` is parsed to two integers for the formats who use it for example. See `AV_OPT_TYPE_IMAGE_SIZE` in `libavutil/opt.c`.

You can define your own options (`AVOption`) for a class. So there's nothing stopping you from adding two options like `video_width` and `video_height` and initialize them via a dictionary.

```
static const AVOption options[] = {
    { "video_width", "frame width", OFFSET(width), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64 = -1 }, -1, INT_MAX, DEC },
    { "video_height", "frame height", OFFSET(height), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64 = -1 }, -1, INT_MAX, DEC },
    { NULL }
};

static const AVClass some_class = {
     [...]
     .option     = options,
     [...]
}
```

where `width` and `height` are members of the struct used by your format.